# how to set headers using Log4j2 with KafkaAppender

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j2

I've already got a successful appender sorted out that sends messages to kafka with no issues, however I was reading the (new) kafka connect book, and was thinking about reading the headers in each kafka log message and use a predicate to work out which transformation to apply, however I can't find anywhere that its mentioned in the log4j2 spec for the appender:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#KafkaAppender

Any experiences with this tech and use case that can be shared?

Comment: Can you please point me how did you made it work... I am keep getting the error as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78243369/kafka-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to write your own appender, or otherwise try to set a Kafka Producer Interceptor to modify the record inflight.

You can see in the source code that headers aren't added to the record.

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/mom/kafka/KafkaManager.java#L156